# polyfit/polyval with log scale through scatter points in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a scatter plot with both x and y axes in log scale in Matlab. How do I add a line of best fit on the log scale?
Thanks!

```
x = [0.0090  0.0000 0.0001 0.0000 0.0001 0.0000 0.0097 0.0016 0.0006 0.0000 0.0016 0.0013 0.0023];
y = [0.0085 0.0001 0.0013 0.0006 0.0005 0.0006 0.0018 0.0076 0.0015 0.0001 0.0039 0.0015 0.0024];
scatter(x,y)
set(gca,'YScale','log');
set(gca,'XScale','log');
hold on
p = polyfit(log(x),log(y),1);
f = polyval(p,x);
plot(x,f,'Color',[0.7500 0.7500 0.7500],'linewidth',2)
```

Comment: How do you plan to `polyfit` infinities? Because that's what you're going to get from log(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching for the best fit, you need to use the original data `x` and `y` and not their logs. The log scale serves only for representation of the result.

Before use the `polyval` you need to sort the `x`. It does not matter when using normal axes, but can look strange with log-axes, because of the wrong sequence.

Here is the plot:

[image]

The code:

```
x = [0.0090  0.0000 0.0001 0.0000 0.0001 0.0000 0.0097 0.0016 0.0006 0.0000 0.0016 0.0013 0.0023];
y = [0.0085 0.0001 0.0013 0.0006 0.0005 0.0006 0.0018 0.0076 0.0015 0.0001 0.0039 0.0015 0.0024];
scatter(x,y);
set(gca,'YScale','log');
set(gca,'XScale','log');
hold on;
x_sort = sort(x);
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
f = polyval(p,x_sort);
plot(x_sort,f,'Color',[0.7500 0.7500 0.7500],'linewidth',2);
```

Is it what you wanted?